# Android error: can't login with email and password

Tags: android

E/login: http://ciyashop.example.comwp-json/pgs-woo-api/v1/login
E/Exception is: Invalid API key
I get these error every time I try to login in the app
layout/activity_log_in.xml/email input:

```
<com.example.ciyashop.customview.edittext.EditTextRegular
                    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                    style="@style/txt_gray_medium"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/value_8"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/value_8"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textDirection="locale"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base"
                    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_user" />
```

layout/activity_log_in.xml/password input:

```
<com.example.ciyashop.customview.edittext.EditTextRegular
                    android:id="@+id/etPass"
                    style="@style/txt_gray_medium"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/value_8"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/value_8"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textDirection="locale"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base"
                    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_password" />
```

i get this error when i play the app on my phone

```
E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: _id}
```

and this error when I try to login

```
E/login: http://ciyashop.example.comwp-json/pgs-woo-api/v1/login
E/Exception is: Invalid Api key
```

in xml/noindex.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<search-engine xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <noindex android:value="notification" />
    <noindex uri="http://example.com/hidden-page"/>
    <noindex uriPrefix="http://example.com/hidden_prefix"/>

</search-engine>
```

this is the app structure I have:

```
app/
  manifasts/
  java/
  java/ (generated)
  assets/
  res/
  res/ (generated)
```

Comment: Please share the body of the request.

Comment: i am new to android so can you tell me what code do you need so i can send you it

Comment: Kindly share the documentation of this API if you can.
Also, share with us the your classes to figure out your problem.

Comment: do you need anything else

Comment: Yes, please, share your requests, http-library you use, responses, errors.

Comment: where can I find them

Comment: in any folder layout / anim / draubal / mipmap / raw / values / xml

Comment: anything else do you need

Comment: @CoolMind I am sorry for my questions but I don't know a thing about android

Comment: How are you performing the web request? What API Endpoint are you trying to reach? We don't know a thing about what you're doing and what you're trying to accomplish. You need to provide more information so we can reason about the question. If you don't know a thing about android, explain how you happend upon the situation so we can help you more effectively

Comment: @jensV is this fine I don't know in what file do I find http request

Comment: @jensV look at my app structure please and tell me what folder do you want me to open and what file do you need)

Comment: Do you use Facebook OAuth? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479365/803-some-of-the-aliases-you-requested-do-not-exist-education-experience-id. Where are your requests? Do you use Retrofit?